# Im trying to figure out why my squars wont fill with the color black when using turtle library

Tags: python-3.x, python-turtle

Im trying to fill some squars with the color black, but it wont fill

my code:

```
from turtle import *
setup(1920,1080,0,0)
k=Turtle()
k.right(45)
størrelse=40
n=int(input("Hvor mange diamanter?  "))
for i in range(n+1):
    color("black")
    if i!=0:
        if i%2!=0:
            begin_fill()
            for c in range(4):
                    k.forward(i*størrelse)
                    k.right(90)
            end_fill()
        else:
            for c in range(4):
                    k.forward(i*størrelse)
                    k.right(90)
    k.penup()
    k.left(90)
    k.forward(størrelse/2)
    k.left(90)
    k.forward(størrelse/2)
    k.left(180)
    k.pendown()

done()
```

If i use this code i only get squars, but they are not filled any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

forgot "k." infront of fill and end function